# Using Twilio API detect incoming messages and read their contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

This is what I want to do as soon as I get Sms:

```
Message received
Read contents
if contents=='abc' do process 1
```

I know how to do it using Ngrok but I do not want to update localhost address in Twilio for every new session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you know how to do this using ngrok, then you're halfway there as you have presumably built the application that performs this task and run it locally.

If you want this to run permanently with a URL that doesn't change, then you will need to deploy your application to a server somewhere, and point a domain at it. Since you're using Python you might try something like [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) to host the application. Alternatively, if you rewrite your application in Node.js you could take advantage of [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) to host your code.

Let me know if this helps at all.